# I add MPAndroidChart in my project but in my xml I cant find LineChart

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I want to use MPAndroidChart in my project.
I add that library in my gradle but in my xml layout file, I cant find Chart.
my build.gradle(Module) is this :

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0' 
}
```

and build.gradle(Project) is this :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

but I cant find Chart in my xml layout file
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in **setting.gradle** file instead of build.gradle(Project)

Answer (score 4):

need to add maven url in setting.gradle add code like this .

```
pluginManagement {
repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
 }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the syntax was different, so just for any other future people facing the same error. I got error **Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)**. The fix was:

```
maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for your issue.
Try inserting this into your `settings.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven ("https://jitpack.io")
        }
    }
```

It works for me.