# I get the error class referenced in the layout file ... was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

implementation('com.kevalpatel2106:ruler-picker:1.1')
```

Here are the codes in the build gradle. The `implementation('com.kevalpatel2106:ruler-picker:1.1')` library at the bottom is the library I'm trying to use and getting the error.

[image]

Here's a simple stack of code that I'm trying to use the library for as well.

Error;
Class referenced in the layout file, `com.kevalpatel2106.rulerpicker.RulerValuePicker`, was not found in the project or the libraries

and;

Cannot resolve class com.kevalpatel2106.rulerpicker.RulerValuePicker

Comment: visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72866015/8691696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps-

1. Download .aar file from [Link](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-ruler-picker/releases/download/v1.1/ruler-picker-1.1.aar)
2. Add that .aar file in app/libs folder in application.
3. Add this line in build.gradle file     `implementation files('libs/ruler-picker-1.1.aar')`
4. No need to change with XML file with your current code.

Find attached screenshot for your reference-
[image]
if its not work confirm with me, I will try to help with same.